# DB2 : search depth first : (syntax) error

Tags: sql, db2, hierarchy

A few days ago I installed DB2 LUW (11.5) on a server to play around with.
Now I would like to do some recursive SQL (Recursive Common Table Expression):

Let me show how I setup :

```
drop table relations;

create table relations (id int, parent int);

insert into relations values(0,NULL);
insert into relations values(1,0);
insert into relations values(2,1);
insert into relations values(3,1);
insert into relations values(4,3);
insert into relations values(5,0);
insert into relations values(6,5);
insert into relations values(7,5);
insert into relations values(8,6);
insert into relations values(9,7);
insert into relations values(10,0);
insert into relations values(11,1);

commit;
```

Now I would like to see the hierarchy in the table. So I tried the following:

```
with recur(id, parent, level) as
  (
    select rel.id id, rel.parent parent, 0 level from relations rel where rel.id=0
    union all
    select rel.id, rel.parent, rec.level+1 from recur rec, relations rel where rec.id=rel.parent
    and rec.level<10
  )
select id, lpad(parent, level*2, ' ') from recur;
```

This gives me:

```
ID          PARENT                                                                                                         
----------- ------------------
          0 -                                                                                                              
          1  0                                                                                                             
          5  0                                                                                                             
         10  0                                                                                                             
          2    1                                                                                                           
          3    1                                                                                                           
         11    1                                                                                                           
          6    5                                                                                                           
          7    5                                                                                                           
          4      3                                                                                                         
          8      6                                                                                                         
          9      7
```

This is (to me) : "Search Breadth First"
What I would like to see is "Search Depth First"

So I did this:

```
with recur(id, parent, level) as
  (
    select rel.id id, rel.parent parent, 0 level from relations rel where rel.id=0
    union all
    select rel.id, rel.parent, rec.level+1 from recur rec, relations rel where rec.id=rel.parent 
    and rec.level<10 
  ) 
  search depth first by parent set ord
select id, lpad(parent, level*2, ' ') parent from recur order by ord;
```

But this delivers to me:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "search depth first by parent set ord sel" was 
found following "t and rec.level<10 )".  Expected tokens may include:  
"<values>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

No clue how to solve it now. I (think I) have tried a lot of possible solutions. But none worked.
I'm starting to believe that DB2 LUW (11.5) doesn't know about Search Depth First. Or some setting must be made to make DB2 aware of the "SDF" possibility.

My question to you all:
How to solve this problem? How do I get Search Depth First to work?

On the positive....following works like a charms....but that is not whatI want tot know :-)

```
select id, lpad(parent, level*2, ' ') parent, level
from   relations 
start with id=0
connect by prior id=parent;

ID          PARENT     LEVEL
----------- ---------- -----------
          0 -                    1
          1    0                 2
          2      1               3
          3      1               3
          4        3             4
         11      1               3
          5    0                 2
          6      5               3
          8        6             4
          7      5               3
          9        7             4
         10    0                 2
```

This works like a charm, but I had tot make a switch in the database (and a restart):

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=08
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff As far as I remember DB2 does not allow join syntax in recursive CTEs, but only old-style joins.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about *displaying* rows in a specific ordering, not about *searching* in a specific ordering.

You can display the rows in the ordering you want by assembling an ordering column that fits your needs.

For example:

```
with
n (id, parent, lvl, ordering) as (
  select id, parent, 1, lpad(id, 3, '0') || lpad('', 30, ' ')
  from relations 
  where parent is null
 union all
  select r.id, r.parent, n.lvl + 1, trim(n.ordering) || '/' || lpad(r.id, 3, '0')
  from n, relations r where r.parent = n.id
)
select id, lpad(parent, lvl * 2, ' ') as parent, lvl
from n
order by ordering;
```

Result:

```
 ID  PARENT    LVL 
 --- --------- --- 
 0             1   
 1      0      2   
 2        1    3   
 3        1    3   
 4          3  4   
 11       1    3   
 5      0      2   
 6        5    3   
 8          6  4   
 7        5    3   
 9          7  4   
 10     0      2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=96f4bfa2c546982af60cc3b52c417fdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for you constructive answer.
I'm a bit hestitant to mark it as the correct one. 

I've got the idea for the "search depth first ....." clause from an IBM aricle : https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/i-db2connectby/ 

So I still hope for an answer that  comments on the usage of "Search Depth First".

If that answer won't come in the next few days I'll mark you answer as the correct one.

Comment: There is Db2 for z/OS, Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows (LUW) and Db2 on IBM i. Your linked article is for Db2 i. If you use Db2 LUW, the supported syntax for Db2 LUW applies... It has CONNECT BY, but not depth first